# Usar mais de uma variável na mesma frase(replace)

Tags: java

Num campo preciso substituir duas palavras por outras duas quaisquer.

Exemplo: Sr(a) v1, o valor da sua fatura é de v2 reais.
Como deve ficar: 
Sr(a) **Joao**, o valor da sua fatura é de **10,00** reais.

Portanto, tenho o seguinte método abaixo.

```
String mensagemI = txtMensagem.getText();

        String var1 = txtVariavel1.getText();
        String var2 = txtVariavel2.getText();
        String var3 = txtVariavel3.getText();

        String mensagemF = mensagemI.replaceAll("v1", var1);

        System.out.println(mensagemF);
```

Mas desta forma, consigo alterar somente uma palavra da frase, neste caso v1.

Existe algum outro método, onde eu consigo alterar duas palavras numa só frase?

Obrigado.

Comment: por que nao chamar o replaceAll 2 vezes ?

Comment: Felipe,
Já tentei, mas dá erro.

Comment: pode postar o código mais recente e completo ? ( se esse for o mais recente note que var1 esta sendo modificada 3 vezes )

Comment: Me desculpe, feito correção.
E este é o código mais recente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que li você quer substituir:

> Sr(a) **V1**, o valor da sua fatura é de **V2** reais.

Mas no código você está dando replace em **v1** (minúsculo).

```
    String mensagemI = "Sr(a) V1, o valor da sua fatura é de V2 reais.\nPague sua fatura em dia V1.";

    String var1 = "Joao";
    String var2 = "10,00";

    String mensagemF = mensagemI.replaceAll("V1", var1).replaceAll("V2", var2);

    System.out.println(mensagemF);
```

Basta ir chamando a função **replaceAll** passando o padrão e o valor que irá substituir. :)

Comment: Show de Bola Laerte.
Funcionou, perfeito.

Muito obrigado a vocês que me ajudaram.